# Importing package compiled as jar: Bad class file, class file contains wrong class and package does not exist error

Tags: java, ant, jar, classpath, package

I have a package I have created, and have used ant to compile it into a jar file.

the file structure goes like this

```
project folder
  x_package
    compiled package_x.jar
    com
      name
        package_x
          Package files
  demos
    src
      files I'm trying to compile
```

I am trying to compile the files under demos/src that have a dependency on compiled package_x.jar

I do this by adding the package_x.jar to the classpath as a argument to the javac task

**Javac task**

```
    <javac destdir = "${build.dir}" source = "${ant.java.version}" target = "${ant.java.version}" 
        debug = "true" deprecation = "false" optimize = "false" failonerror = "true" >
        <src path = "${source.dir}" />
        <classpath refid = "master-classpath"/>
    </javac>
```

**master-classpath**

```
    <path id = "master-classpath" > 
        <fileset dir = "${classpath.dir}" >
            <include name = "*.jar" />
        </fileset>
        <pathelement path = "${classpath.dir}" />
    </path>
```

Whenever I run the ant file, 2 errors happen

```
error: package package_x does not exist
```

and at the first reference to an class defined in the package

```
error: Cannot access class_name
bad class file C:/(path)/package_x.jar (class_name)
class file contains wrong class: package_x.class_name
please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath
```

in the package_x package every file starts with

```
package package_x;
/*code*/
```

and the files in the demos directory have

```
import package_x.*;
/*code*/
```

any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the only problem, but in the package declaration and the import you have to write the full package path, like com.name.package_x